# How to merge 2 Observables in nestjs Interceptor()?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nestjs

I am developping a nestjs interceptor to geolocate an address I am sending throught a rest API.
Here is the code:

```
export class PointsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {

    var monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body
    const geoPremiseToObservable = from(geocoder.geocode(monaddress));
    geoPremiseToObservable.subscribe(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)));

    return next.handle().pipe(map(value => console.log(value)))
  }

}
```

The result of this code is:

- a **JSON** coming from the **http response**:

```
{
  address: '123, avenue des Champs Elysées, 75008 PARIS',
  _id: new ObjectId("64bd089088f925780705bbbd"),
  __v: 0
}
```

- An **Object** coming from **geoCoder**

```
[{"latitude":48.872438,"longitude":2.29811,"state":"75, Paris, Île-de-France","city":"Paris","zipcode":...}]
```

My wish is to have all of this concatenated in one JSON that will be "pushed to the database".
I tried to apply a **merge** or even a **mergeWith**. In vain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try `tap`, like this, so instead of subscribing , get using `from` and then tap both. Apologies if this does not work, it is not tested

```
export class PointsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body;
    const geocodeResult = from(geocoder.geocode(monaddress));
    const geoCoder = await lastValueFrom(geocodeResult);

    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(value => console.log(value)),
      map(value => {
        //1: Returning an object from both next.handle() and geoPremiseToObservable
        return {
          httpResponse: value,
          geoCoder: geoCoder
        };

       //2: Returning an single object by merging the geocoder response with http response
        return {
          ...value,
          geoCoder: geoCoder
        };
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not procuce one JSON for 2 Observables. I need: {} {} transformed into one {}

Comment: Did you mean to include `[{"latitude":48.872438,"longitude":2.29811,"state":"75, Paris, Île-de-France","city":"Paris","zipcode":...}]` inside the http response as a key?
Like {address: '', _id: '', __v: '', geoCoder: GEOCODER-RESPONSE} ??

Comment: Yes  I mean { "address":"12 blabla street", "latitude":48.872438,"longitude":2.29811,"state":"75 } so yes something like {address: '', _id: '', __v: '', geoCoder: GEOCODER-RESPONSE}

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I have written both of them, whichever you prefer

Comment: Thanks but I fear geoPremiseToObservable is never subscribed here so there is no data

Comment: Pleae check now, I missed this line `const geoCoder = await lastValueFrom(geocodeResult)`

Comment: Thanks. Both are returned. How could I see the complete returned object? This would help me associating the corresponding Model. Model + Dto are bad now so I need to change them according to what is returned. I will fine tune later. An idea?

Comment: I need further input on what you actually want to do

Comment: I will add another Stackoverflow question and provide you with the link

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76753771/how-to-push-data-after-response-has-been-intercepted-using-nest-js-interceptors