# How to push data after response has been intercepted using nest.js interceptors?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am sorry if my request sounds easy but I am very new to nestJs.

The goal of my code I have a problem with is:

- I enter a physical address through a swagger api.
- I geolocate this address.
- I want to save both the address and the geolocation result.

For this,
I have 2 observables that get data through a nestjs interceptor (before saving to database) and would like to push this data into my database. I am using mongoose=>mongoDB.

The **points.interceptor.ts** code is:

```
export class PointsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<any>> {

    var monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body
    const geocodeResult = from(geocoder.geocode(monaddress));
    const geoCoder = await lastValueFrom(geocodeResult);
    return next.handle().pipe(
 //     tap(value => console.log(value)),
      map(value => {
        // Returning an object from both next.handle() and geoPremiseToObservable
        return {
          ...value,
          geoCoder: geoCoder
        }
      })
      )
  }

}
```

What I can see through VSCode debugger is that data is here when excecuting next.handle():
[image]

The **points.schema.ts** is:

```
export const PointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  address: String,
  geocoded: Object
});
```

The **create-point.dto.ts** is:

```
export class CreatePointDto {
    readonly address: string;
    readonly geocoded: Object;
```

The **point.service.ts** is

```
@Injectable()
export class PointsService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('POINT_MODEL')
    private PointModel: Model<Point>,
  ) {}

  async create(createPointDto: CreatePointDto): Promise<Point> {
    const createdPoint = new this.PointModel(createPointDto);
    return createdPoint.save();
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<Point[]> {
    return this.PointModel.find().exec();
  }
}
    }
```

The **point.controller.ts** is :

```
export class PointsController {
  constructor(private readonly pointsService: PointsService) {}

  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(PointsInterceptor)
  create(@Body() createPointDto: CreatePointDto) {
     return this.pointsService.create(createPointDto);
  }

  @Get()
  findAll() {
    return this.pointsService.findAll();
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for every help.

Comment: Can you add your controller screenshot too

Comment: I Just did modify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be relatively simple task, but you have to understand how interceptor works.

Inside interceptor, whatever you do before `return` will be done before it goes to the service/controller and whatever you do after `return` will be done after the lifespan of the service/controller.

Lets change your interceptor a bit to do your work

```
const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
if(request.body) {
  // I dont have  information how you are expecting the address in the controller, Im assuming you are passing as string
  const monaddress = request.body;
  const geocodeResult = from(geocoder.geocode(monaddress));
  const geocoded = await lastValueFrom(geocodeResult);

  // matching with your create-point.dto
  request.body = {
    address: monaddress
    geocoded: geocoded
  }
}
```

so this will modify your request body to have the geocoded field with the decoded data and will be available in the service itself

Comment: I did:  context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body = {
    address: monaddress,
    geocoded: geocoded
} instead of request and now getting an error : [Nest] 90784  - 24/07/2023 14:00:11   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Point validation failed: address: Cast to string failed for value "{ address: '20 Rue de Vaugirard, 75006 Paris' }" (type Object) at path "address" . So I changed string in Dto + schema with Object => result is written in the database. Thank you very much for you great help !!!

Comment: How could I suppress the [] in the result? I am using an object: "geocoded": [
    {
      "latitude": 48.849276,
      "longitude": 2.338211,
      "state": "75, Paris, Île-de-France",
      "city": "Paris",
      "zipcode": "75006",
      "citycode": "75106",
      "countryCode": "FR",
      "country": "France",
      "type": "housenumber",
      "id": "75106_9624_00020",
      "streetName": "Rue de Vaugirard",
      "streetNumber": "20",
      "provider": "opendatafrance"
    }
  ],

Comment: You can return the same response that are going from the interceptor or return directly from the service